# ArgumentError: invalid index: :Position of type Symbol

Tags: julia

I'm trying to run a julia script, but I keep getting this error [terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiiC9.png)

I've tried adding a delim arguments like the example in the documentation, but that didn't work.

here is the code:

```
# Load information for skaters table
skaters = CSV.File(path_skaters, normalizenames=true, delim=",")

# Load information for goalies table
goalies = CSV.File(path_goalies, normalizenames=true, delim=",")
```

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: The error you reference with "terminal error" does not appear to originate from the lines of code you provided.

Comment: If you post six lines before and a few lines after line 873
in your file /Users/aus10/Fantasy-Hockey-IP-Code/code_for_Github.jl
We might see the problem.
(It is possible that deleting lines 872,873,874 and retyping them could help, too)